# Ruby passing multiple parameters in methods

Tags: ruby, parameters, arguments

Actually i am trying to use third parameter as method as get and second parameter as *p but it throws error

```
def ss(a,*b,method="GET")
    puts a 
end
ss("fff",98,"POST")
```

The above code throws error

```
li.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
def ss(a,*b,method="GET")
               ^
li.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
```

How to make this program work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
def ss(a,method="GET", *b)
 puts a
end
```

<del>When splat operators are used to accept multiple inputs, it should always be the last parameter of a method.</del> Also a method can have only one splat parameter.

Thanks Cary for a clear and crisp explanation over how to use splats:

> Basically, the rule is that if it's unambiguous, it's OK--Ruby will
>   figure it out. If, however, you add a variable with a default value to
>   my example *(`def test(*a,b); p a; p b; end; test 1,2,3`)*, it becomes ambiguous, so Ruby will complain.

Comment: The splatted argument does not necessarily have to be at the end: `def test(*a,b); p a; p b; end; test 1,2,3` prints `[1,2]` then `3`.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. I have strike that out of my answer. Thanks

Comment: Basically, the rule is that if it's unambiguous, it's OK--Ruby will figure it out. If, however, you add a variable with a default value to my example, it becomes ambiguous, so Ruby will complain.